# What kind of equivalences exist between categories of characteristic $0$ and characteristic $p$?

Tags: positive-characteristic

The tilting equivalence for perfectoid algebras gives an equivalence of categories $$K\text{-perf} \cong K^\flat\text{-perf}$$
where the left-hand-side are algebras in characteristic zero and the right-hand-side are in characteristic $p$.

Are there any other non-trivial examples of an equivalence of categories relating characteristic zero things (rings, or schemes, or whatever) on one side to characteristic $p$ things on the other?

Comment: A trivial example: vector spaces. Slightly less trivial: representations.

Comment: How are vector spaces an example?

Comment: I think the category of split reductive algebraic groups, with morphisms isomorphisms, is an example, I think, because the objects and morphisms may be described combinatorially.

Comment: I'd like to consider such examples (where one artificially restricts the set of morphisms) to be trivial.